# Thumbnails with one height

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, thumbnails

I want my thumbnails to have the same height. Take a look at the picture:
[image]
I tried this code I foud there:

```
  function equalHeight(group) {    
            var tallest = 0;    
            group.each(function() {       
              var thisHeight = $(this).height();       
              if(thisHeight > tallest) {          
                tallest = thisHeight;       
              }    
            });    
            group.each(function() { $(this).height(tallest); });
          }
```

But it doesn't count image size. Also it can't handle window size changings. How to fix that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make Bootstrap columns all the same height?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you the use of flexbox: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Comment: Yup. It works. This link saved my day. https://codepen.io/bootstrapped/pen/OMNYpq